# Using complex css properties via javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How do I use the following css in javascript

```
#absoluteCenter {
left: 50% !important;
top: 50% !important;
-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%)!important;
-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%)!important;
-ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%)!important;
-o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%)!important;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%)!important;
}
```

I want to use it in the form of an object so I can pass a style object to a component. So it should be in this form:

```
var styles = {
style: property
}
```

Edit: I am using ReactJS, so these properties are defined before the Component is rendered to the DOM. Which is why I can't use document.getElementById()

Comment: Make that a css class, then add the class to the element in JS, it is possible to do all that in JS but why bother

Comment: Try to do this: `var property = "left: 50% !important; ..."`. Just copy & paste your CSS without white spaces into that string.

Comment: What is happening with all those `!important`s? Why not use classes and assign a class where necessary? That way you could have a CSS preprocessor fill in the necessary vendor prefixes so you didn't have to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this through JS have a look at the below code: (Though I would recommend creating a style class and adding to html)

```
var myStyle="webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%); -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%); -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%)!important,transform:translate(-50%,-50%); width:600px;" ;
    document.getElementById("absoluteCenter").setAttribute("style", myStyle);
```